# Conditional Distribution of $Y$ Given $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

In [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/118) and [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/96), it appears to be proven that under the following conditions:

1) $Y$ follows a normal distribution $N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$, (2) $X$ follows a normal distribution $N(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$ (Note: $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily independent), and (3) $E(Y|x)$, the conditional mean of $Y$ given $x$ is linear in $x$, then:

$$E(Y|x)=\mu_Y+\rho \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x−\mu_X) \cdots (*)$$

But no proof is given, can anyone show me how this is proven? Also note, that there is no mention of whether $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate normal, if they were then the above result is easy to show.

Put simply, my question is: Is is true that if 1) $Y \sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$, 2) $X \sim N(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$, 3) Correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is $\rho$, 4) $E(Y|x)$ is linear in $x$, then $(*)$ holds?

If true, how does one go about proving it? I have never seen this result anywhere, I have only seen the expression $(*)$ appear when $(X, Y)$ are bivariate normal as it is simply the mean of the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the assumption, we can let $E[Y|X] = aX + b$, where $a, b$ are constants yet to be determined. Taking expectation on both sides, we have

$$ E[E[Y|X]] = aE[X] + b \Rightarrow \mu_Y = a\mu_X  + b$$

On the other hand consider the covariance, by definition

$$ Cov[X, Y] = \rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y $$

By the law of total covariance, we have
$$ Cov[X, Y] = E[Cov[X, Y|X]] + Cov[E[X|X], E[Y|X]] = 0 + Cov[X,aX+b] = a\sigma_X^2 $$

Equating the above two equations, we have
$$ a\sigma_X^2 = \rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y \Rightarrow a 
= \rho\frac {\sigma_Y} {\sigma_X}$$

and putting all the results together

$$ E[Y|X] = aX + b = aX + \mu_Y - a\mu_X = \mu_Y + a(X - \mu_X) 
= \mu_Y + \rho\frac {\sigma_Y} {\sigma_X}(X - \mu_X)  $$

Note that here we do not need any of the normality assumptions. So this results holds in general, and in particular you should see similar result in linear regression too.

Comment: Thanks! What if we don’t assume linearity of $E(Y|x)$, can we still derive the same result?

Comment: Of course you need the linearity assumption to derive this result.